# Creating Edit dialog box in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, architecture

I have Form1.cs which has two buttons say "ADD" and "EDIT".

Clicking "ADD" shows dialog Form2.cs.

Form2 has a TextBox and a ComboBox. Say we enter value "A" in textbox and select "A" from ComboBox.
Then close Form2.

Then when EDIT button is clicked on Form1, Form2 should show up with "A" in textbox and "A" selected in ComboBox.

This is a simple explanation. The real form I am using has around 10-12 different controls including combobox, checkbox, textbox etc.

My main doubt is where and how do we save these control values.

Is there a specific approach to this type of DialogBoxes that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create class, that would store values that you want to pass (let's call it `Foo`).

`Form2` should then have a property. In the setter of the property, set controls:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Foo _bar;
    public Foo Bar
    {
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
            //set your controls here
        }
    }
```

On Edit button, set property like this:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Bar = bar; //bar contains values to edit
```

Then put a Save button on `Form2`, that would save values back from controls to this object.

For every control I would have a field in `Foo` class, eg. `string` for textboxes, `bool` for checkboxes and `enum` or `int` for comboboxes (where integer value would equal selected index).
Alternatively, you could use `Dictionary` class instead and have key and value pair for every control.

You can also have some `enum`, if your form looks or behaves differently in New and Edit mode.

Comment: What should the Foo class look like?
I mean, how can we store something like KEY (i.e. say control name),VALUE (i.e. say control value) pair for several types of controls (checkbox, combobox, textbox etc) inside Foo ?
I believe thats the concept of the Foo class.

Comment: For each of controls I would have separate field or property in this class. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to just load the last value user entered there?

For instance he writes "text" on the textbox and chooses "A" combobox it should be pre-selected next time you open it?

Edit: Then instead of closing it using Form.Close make it so that it hides. Form1.Hide. Next time it opens values are still saved. Unless application has been closed. In the other hand, users might click on the close button in the windows form. You can either make it "unclickable" throught proprieties or just configure it using events i think.

Comment: ohh sorry for not coming back to you on this. I haven't tried it, but I guess it is going to work. 
My concern remains that:
The actual form I am using has multiple controls and users can keep on clicking ADD button several times.
Every time a new Form2 is created as there are other stuff which work with the return value of the form. It has to be a new form every time.
So hiding the form could cause some memory problems. I am marking your answer as useful, as it can be one of the solutions. I will still look for an ideal one. Thanks.

Comment: @dushyantp Hope you fixed it mate. Good luck. If you need help in the code i can help.

Comment: thanks for your help. I used an object of user-defined class to store the values, like Tschareck has described in the answer on this post. It worked for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your Dialog Form should have a field containing the properties/fields you want, a copy a business object for example. Then you pass it or initialize it in your dialog constructor or Load, depending the behavior you want. From there you can create / initialize your controls.

If you want a built in system you may wanna take a look to the PropertyGrid (which you could embedded in a dialog (to fit your question))

Comment: Quoting you @Max.gd "Your Dialog Form should have a field containing the properties/fields you want", are you implying there is an object in the Form which holds the control values? Or am I getting it wrong, please can you explain?

Comment: There is nothing build-in for the behavior you are looking for no (Except with the property grid). But you can add one which would be, in the simplest case, a copy of the object you are editing. It would contain at least all the values you want to edit.
`...
Car _myCar;

void MyDialog(Car myCar){
  _myCar = myCar;
}

void Load(){
  textBoxBrand.Text = _myCar.Brand.ToString();
  ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a method on Form2, where you will set values into textBox and select an item in comboBox. Call this method just after instantiating form2 and before showing it.
Example:

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" });//fill comboBox your way on a loading time
    }

    public void UpdatingControls(string a, string b)
    {
        textBox1.Text = a;
        comboBox1.SelectedText = b;
    }
    //on form2;
    Form1 f2;
    private void OpenForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2 = new Form2();
        f2.UpdatingControls("a", "b"); //a will go into textBox, b will be choosen in comboBox
    }
```

Comment: I did a edit to the question, wasn't clear enough :)
My main doubt is where do you save the control values? Is it array list, config file or do we have a specific arch concept for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form2(string form1Textbox)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form2Textbox.Text = form1Textbox;
}
```

Comment: I did an edit to the question, wasn't clear enough :) My main doubt is where do you save the control values? Is it array list, config file or do we have a specific arch concept for this?

Comment: Well thats up to you. If you only need the values for a short time use a singleton object. Longer time database or xml file.